# Second derivative of a pertiular function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Which of the following statements are true about $f(x)$
>    $$ f(x) =\begin{cases}
> x^2 & x<0\\
> 2x+x^2 & x \geq 0
> \end{cases}$$
>
> (A) $f''(x)=2, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> (B) $f''(0)$ does not exist.
>
> (C) $f'(x)$ exists for each $x \neq 0$
>
> (D) $f'(0)$ does not exist

I am pretty much convinced that $(B)$ and $(D)$ are correct. But the answer key says otherwise. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are certainly correct about B and D, but don't forget C! For every non-zero $x$, we have that $f'(x)$ exists (since other than at zero, $f(x)$ is described simply as a polynomial, which has as many derivatives as you like).

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,2x\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,x<0  \\
   2+2x\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,x>0  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$
**A:** we should say that $f$ is continues at $x=2$  and $f'_{+}(2)=f'_{-}(2)=6 $ and $f''(2)=2$

**B,C,D:**  $f$ is continues at $x=0$  and $f'_{-}(0)=0 $ whereas $f'_{+}(0)=2$. As a result there is not $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about $f$ being continuous at $x = 2$... the question is about $f''(x) = 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: if $f$ is not continues at $x=2$ then there is not $f''(2)$. for example $g(x)=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{x}^{2}}+1\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\le 2 \\ 
 & {{x}^{2}}-1\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\le 2 \\ 
\end{align} \right.$  
g is not continues at $x=2$ whereas $g''_{+}(2)=g''_{-}(2)=2$

Comment: sorry $$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   x^2+1\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\le 2  \\
   x^2-1\,\,,\,\,\,\,\,x>2 \\
\end{matrix} \right.$$

Comment: True, but this function is continuous at $x = 2$, since in a neighbourhood of that point the function is equal to $2x + x^2$.

Comment: yes but we should checked it